# What section of OS code is related to the kernel?

Tags: kernel

What section of OS code is related to the kernel?

I understand the system diagram, but I have assignment about the coding part.

Comment: So, basically you need us to do your homework for you?

Comment: Not exactly, i need the highlight, i asked after i googled it for a long time and no result. You know the answer please answer, if you dont know then dont waste you energy.

Answer (score 2):

... The 'kernel' section ([Linux](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/?id=refs/tags/v4.11-rc3) / [QNX](http://www.qnx.com/developers/docs/6.4.1/neutrino/sys_arch/kernel.html) / [BSD](https://github.com/freebsd/freebsd), etc...)

You need to define what you mean by 'related', because you *could* try argue that *all* code is *related* to the kernel:

- Without the kernel, *nothing* will run - not even in user-space.
- Without the user-space applications, a system is largely useless.

Additionally, depending on the type of kernel, other parts of the system are more or less strongly related.

- **[Monolithinc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monolithic_kernel)** (e.g: Linux) is a large code base, where things like drivers typically live inside the kernel
- **[Hybrid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hybrid_kernel)** (e.g: Windows), components are split between kernel and user space
- **[Microkernel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microkernel)** (e.g: QNX) is a relatively small code base, where drivers are implemented as user-space 'applications'

Of course, this doesn't work for 'baremetal' systems that might not even use a kernel per se.

---

Diving deeper in to the Linux kernel (as requested), you start to see that there are major sub-systems:

- [Architecture (Machine) specific support](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/arch?id=refs/tags/v4.11-rc3) ([x86](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/arch/x86?id=refs/tags/v4.11-rc3))
- [Initialization Routines](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/init?id=refs/tags/v4.11-rc3)
- [Scheduler](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/kernel/sched?id=refs/tags/v4.11-rc3)
- [Interrupt Handling](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/kernel/irq?id=refs/tags/v4.11-rc3)
- [Memory Management](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/mm?id=refs/tags/v4.11-rc3)
- [Device Support (aka 'Drivers')](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/drivers?id=refs/tags/v4.11-rc3) ([MMC](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/drivers/mmc/host?id=refs/tags/v4.11-rc3))
- [File Systems](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/fs?id=refs/tags/v4.11-rc3) ([ext4](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/fs/ext4?id=refs/tags/v4.11-rc3))
- [Inter-Process Communication](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/ipc?id=refs/tags/v4.11-rc3)
- [Networking](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/net?id=refs/tags/v4.11-rc3) ([IPv4](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/net/ipv4?id=refs/tags/v4.11-rc3))
- ... the list goes on

Each of these sub-systems have further sub-systems (some are shown in brackets above).

You could have a diagram as you suggested in your comment, but it would get quite complex.

It might be a good idea to read through an article like '*[Anatomy of the Linux kernel](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/l-linux-kernel/)*' to get a better understanding of what's going on.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, if we take the linux as example, is it possible to imagine it as a huge code, with many modules ( kerenl as example) so the question is, can we have a diagram of the linux code where the main code is calling this function and that function. Sorry if my question is stupid.

Comment: @Fhh updated as requested